# bpf helpers: how to convert struct sock *sk to struct xdp_sock *?

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, xdp-bpf

Given a `struct socket *sock` I basically try to do the following:

```c
struct sock {
    struct sock_common __sk_common;
} __attribute__((preserve_access_index));

struct socket {
    struct sock *sk; // sic! a pointer
} __attribute__((preserve_access_index));

struct net_device {
    int ifindex;
} __attribute__((preserve_access_index));

struct xdp_sock {
    struct sock sk;
    struct net_device *dev;
    u16 queue_id;
} __attribute__((preserve_access_index));

struct sock *sk = sock->sk;
if (sk->__sk_common.skc_family != AF_XDP) {
    return 0;
}
struct xdp_sock *xs = (struct xdp_sock *)sk;
struct net_device *dev = xs->dev;
```

Not totally unexpected, the eBPF verifier isn't exactly amused:

```
load program: permission denied: access beyond struct sock at off 776 size 8
```

A deeper look into [bpf-helpers(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html) as well as in libbpf's v1.1.0 `bpf_helper_defs.h` doesn't show any sign of any helper like `bpf_skc_to_tcp_sock` but instead for XDP sockets.

How do I correctly dynamically cast an "sk" into a `struct xdp_sock *` that is accepted by the verifier?

Comment: Do you have a CO-RE struct definition for `struct xdp_sock`? What is it?

Comment: I've updated the snippet with the xdp_sock and net_device CO-RE "skeletons".

Comment: I'm not super familiar with how the `preserve_access_index` in CO-RE work exactly, but could the fact that you didn't fully define `struct sock` cause issues when trying to compute the offset for `xdp_sock->dev`?

Comment: Yes and no; xdp_sock is containing sock as its "base type". The TCP sockets work similar, but for them are helpers.